# BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I'm setting up react with webpack, here is my webpack config file \n

```js
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "src", "index.js"),
    devtool: 'sourcemaps',
    cache: true,
    mode: 'development',
    output: {
        path:path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        filename: './dist/bundle.js'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.?js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader",
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "public/templates/", "budget_account2.html"),
        }),
    ],
}
```

when i run `npm run-script watch` then it throw error: \n

> Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialized using a
> configuration object that does not match the API schema.
>
> - configuration.devtool should match pattern "^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$".
>   BREAKING CHANGE since webpack 5: The devtool option is more strict.
>   Please strictly follow the order of the keywords in the pattern.

Thanks all

Comment: I hit this issue this morning when I found a `-d` argument in the command line

Answer (score 4):

It's exactly as the error says.

> configuration.devtool should match pattern "`^(inline-|hidden-|eval-)?(nosources-)?(cheap-(module-)?)?source-map$`".

See a description of the various options [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/).

To follow it, your devtool value should:

- Optionally start with `inline-`, `hidden-`, or `eval-`, depending on where you want the source map to be
- Optionally followed by `nosources-`, if you want the source code to be excluded from the map
- Optionally followed by `cheap` or `cheap-module` - `cheap` indicates a fast rebuild time, and `module` preserves the original lines
- Followed by `source-map` at the end.

Figure out which one(s) of the above you want, construct a string that matches, and use that. For a random example, you could have `inline-nosources-cheap-source-map`.

(You may also use `none`, to omit source maps entirely)

Comment: thanks @CertainPerformance for you feedback. it's quite straightforward message so i have tried many cases but still face same issue, even with the one you suggest. surely the file config is updated with new content.

Comment: It fixed the problem for me. devtool: 'source-map' works fine now. Can't see why you still had an issue.

Comment: Having the same issue. Specified devtoll: "souce-map" on the configuration but it still complains

Comment: `"none"` does not work. It complains that that does match pattern. You must pass `false` instead